# jQuery autocomplete : i can't see suggestion

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, autocomplete

I want to make autocomplete and getting data from database
This my code :

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: 'consultation/commande_tags.php'
  });
});
</script>


<form method="post" action="#" class="formstyle1">
<input type="type" name="piece_a_commander" id="tags" placeholder="Réference "  />
</form>
```

the json page

```
 <?php
    if($_GET["term"]){
    include "includes/connexion_bdd.php";
    $ref=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["term"]); 
    $rq_tags="SELECT * FROM piece WHERE reference_p LIKE '%".$ref."%'  ";
    $ret_tags=mysql_query($rq_tags) or die (mysql_error());
    $array = array();
    while ($tab_tags=mysql_fetch_array($ret_tags)){ 
    array_push($array,$tab_tags['reference_p']);
    }
    echo json_encode($array );
    }

    ?>
```

I cant see any suggestion,please help me to see where is the error?

Comment: source is array for auto suggestion not php page...u need to ajax loading when page loaded then put it in an array use that array in source thenit will work..check this once http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: @nickle that is not true [API](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) shows that you can have a string pointing to a resource that will return JSON

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

**REPLACE**

```
$().ready(function() {
 $( "#tags" ).autocomplete("consultation/commande_tags.php", {
    width: 108,
    matchContains: true,
    //mustMatch: true,
    //minChars: 0,
    //multiple: true,
    //highlight: false,
    //multipleSeparator: ",",
    selectFirst: false
});
});
```

**CONNECTION :**

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$pass="";
$bdd="paralel";

// connexion
$con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass)or die(mysql_error());

//selection bdd
```

$db = mysql_select_db($bdd,$con)or die(mysql_error());

```
?>
```

Comment: thanks Mani for your fast answer ,  i tried your code but still the same problem when i write in the php page this line
    <?php echo " [ \"  test \" ]" ;?>
    or simply  ["kaka","koko","kiki"]
 it work

Comment: i see that the problem is with this the include of database connection , i am not good in JSON so i can't see where is the problem in this line  the content of connexion_bdd.php is :
 
    <?php
    $host="localhost";
    $user="root";
    $pass="";
    $bdd="paralel";

    // connexion
    mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass)or die(mysql_error());

    //selection bdd
    mysql_select_db($bdd)or die(mysql_error());

    ?>

Comment: change connection as like above

Comment: the same problem , maybe i should change source to ajax callback ?